# Diagrama de classe x Banco de dados

Tags: banco-de-dados, postgresql, diagrama-de-classes

Tenho um diagrama de classes e gostaria de saber como construo o banco de dados. Segue o cenário:

- Com as classes abaixo tenho uma Demanda que possui um solicitante e um analista, logo do lado de cada uma das classes devo ter uma lista de demandas?
- Nesse caso como ficaria o banco de dados, id solicitante e id analistas seriam PK nas suas tabelas e fk na tabela DEMANDAS?
- e no caso da lista de demandas em Solicitantes e Analistas como ficaria no BD, qual tipo de dado?

Solicitante

> ```
> - ID_SOLICITANTE
> - NOME
> - LOTACAO
> - DEMANDAS (LIST)
> ```

Analista

> ```
> - ID_ANALISTA
> - NOME
> - EQUIPE
> - DEMANDAS (LIST)
> ```

Demandas

> ```
> ID_DEMANDA
> NRO_TICKET
> PRIORIDADE
> ANALISTA (Tipo: Analista)
> SOLICITANTE (Tipo: Solicitante)
> ```

Comment: E qual é o gerenciador de banco de dados: Oracle Database? MySQL? SQl Server? _etc_

Comment: PostgreSQL eh o sgdb.

Answer (score 0):

**Com as classes abaixo tenho uma Demanda que possui um solicitante e um analista, logo do lado de cada uma das classes devo ter uma lista de demandas?**

Não entendi muito bem essa pergunta, mas se você quer saber como usar ela num objeto da linguagem que escolheu, você deve criar uma classe `Analista` e `Solicitante` e ter uma variável do tipo `Analista` e `Solicitante` na classe `Demanda`

**Nesse caso como ficaria o banco de dados, id solicitante e id analistas seriam PK nas suas tabelas e fk na tabela DEMANDAS?**

Sim, assim como tu determina a PK tu tabém pode determinar as FK, existe diversas formas de fazer isso. [Uma forma é](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_foreignkey.asp):

```
...
id_solicitante int NOT NULL,
...
FOREIGN KEY (id_solicitante) REFERENCES solicitante (id_solicitante),
```

**e no caso da lista de demandas em Solicitantes e Analistas como ficaria no BD, qual tipo de dado?**

O mesmo na tabela onde ela é PK (geralmente int ou bigint), mas não `auto_increment`